# How to extract terms from equation, and then set each of them to 0?

Tags: expression-manipulation

I have a long equation, namely,

```
equ = 4576.66 a[1] Cos[t] + 3.3877 a[1]^3 Cos[t]^3 + 4576.65 a[2] Cos[2 t] + 10.1631 a[1]^2 a[2] Cos[t]^2 Cos[2 t] + 10.1631 a[1] a[2]^2 Cos[t] Cos[2 t]^2 + 3.3877 a[2]^3 Cos[2 t]^3 + 4576.63 a[3] Cos[3 t] + 10.1631 a[1]^2 a[3] Cos[t]^2 Cos[3 t] + 20.3262 a[1] a[2] a[3] Cos[t] Cos[2 t] Cos[3 t] + 10.1631 a[2]^2 a[3] Cos[2 t]^2 Cos[3 t] + 10.1631 a[1] a[3]^2 Cos[t] Cos[3 t]^2 + 10.1631 a[2] a[3]^2 Cos[2 t] Cos[3 t]^2 + 3.3877 a[3]^3 Cos[3 t]^3 - 0.415 a[1] Sin[t] - 0.83 a[2] Sin[2 t] - 1.245 a[3] Sin[3 t] == 2/625 Cos[theta] Cos[t w] - 2/625 Sin[theta] Sin[t w]
```

Since `Sin[t]*Cos[t]^3` and so on is a small term, we can take it as 0. Consequently, we would like to eliminate sin[t] and cos[t] to the power of n. My instinct is to use `Cases` to achieve it, but I don't how to make it.

For example, I want keep `4576.66 a[1] Cos[t]` and `4576.65 a[2] Cos[2 t]`, but set `4576.65 a[2] Cos[2 t]` and `10.1631 a[1]^2 a[2] Cos[t]^2 Cos[2 t]` to `0`.

### More Information

1. Aside from `Cos[t]^2` and `Cos[2t]^3`, `Sin[t]*Cos[t]` and `Sin[t]^2*Sin[2t]` and so on should be eliminate. **In other words**, only `Sin[t]` `Sin[2t]` `Sin[3t]`... `Sin[n*t]` and `Cos[t]` `Cos[2t]` `Cos[3t]`... `Cos[n*t]` should be left.
2. Terms like `Sin[theta] Sin[t w]` should survive, because `Sin[theta]` is a constant.

### Summary of the solution

Use the following wolfram language grammar to extract the expected term: `_ h   any expression with head h`. Please refer to [Patterns and Transformation Rules](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsAndTransformationRules.html)

Comment: `equ/.{ Cos[_]^2->0,Cos[_]^3->0}` will set squares and cubes of Cosine equal to zero. `equ/.{ Cos[_]^_->0}` will set all powers of Cosine equal to zero, where `Cos[x]` is not recognized as `Cos[x]^1` and thus will not be changed. Can you use this to accomplish all you want?

Comment: @Bill Your solution suggestive, but it can not solve my problem completely. Please refer to the **More Information** in the main post.

Comment: Should terms like `Sin[theta] Sin[t w]` survive?

Comment: @Natas Yes, because `Sin[theta]` is a constant.

Comment: Since you want set powers of both `Sin` and `Cos` to zero I am guessing the parameters `a[_]` are small? Perhaps then `equ /. {Power[a[_], exp_ /; exp >= 2] :> 0, HoldPattern[Times[a[_], a[_]]] :> 0}` would work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
equ /. HoldPattern[ Power[_Cos | _Sin, _] | 
   Times[(Cos | Sin)[Except[theta]], (Cos | Sin)[Except[theta]], ___]] -> 0
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I got your point, and I add the new knowledge at the end of my main post.